# ACL working but checkboxes not selected in role edit form

Tags: module, extensions, adminhtml, magento-1, acl

I have coded a module with 3 features (and 3 menupoints). Then i copied the menu-section and edited it so it is useable as ACL resource.

It looks like this (adminhtml.xml):

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <MyModule translate="title" module="MyModule">
            <title>MyModule</title>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
            <children>
                <feature1 translate="title" module="MyModule">
                    <title>F1</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>MyModule/index/feature1</action>
                </feature1>
                <feature2>
                    <title>F2</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>MyModule/index/feature2</action>
                </feature2>
                <feature3>
                    <title>F3</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <action>MyModule/index/feature3</action>
                </feature3>
            </children>
        </MyModule>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <MyModule translate="title" module="MyModule">
                        <title>MyModule</title>
                        <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <feature1 translate="title" module="MyModule">
                                <title>F1</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </feature1>
                            <feature2>
                                <title>F2</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </feature2>
                            <feature3>
                                <title>F3</title>
                                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            </feature3>
                        </children>
                    </MyModule>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

now the strange thing is, it is working, but in magento if I edit the the roles it doesnt show up as checked its always unchecked in role resources.
I even checked the database and it saved the correct value (allow/deny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this error on two Systems when i posted it here, but it seems to be there was an error in our setup of magento, i dont know where exactly, but when i tried it on a third magento setup it worked as it should.

So i assume there was nothing wrong with the module, but with the way i installed magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem was with this **xml node**

```
<MyModule translate="title" module="MyModule">
```

make it camel-case

```
<myModule translate="title" module="MyModule">
```

or make it lowercase (in my case lower is worked)

```
<mymodule translate="title" module="MyModule">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the following to your code:

```
<all>
    <title>Allow Everything</title>
</all>
```

So your acl part looks like this:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <MyModule translate="title" module="MyModule">
                    <title>MyModule</title>
                    <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <feature1 translate="title" module="MyModule">
                            <title>F1</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </feature1>
                        <feature2>
                            <title>F2</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </feature2>
                        <feature3>
                            <title>F3</title>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                        </feature3>
                    </children>
                </MyModule>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it didn't fix my problem :/

Comment: Did you logout and log back in to the admin ?

Comment: I assigned the role to another user. When I login with that user the role is applied correctly, for example if I only allow MyModule, I only get the Menupoint from MyModule.

Answer (score 0):

The resource identifiers should be all lowercase. You can see in [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_Tab_Rolesedit](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Tab/Rolesedit.php#L105) that `strtolower()` is used on the identifier when it's determined if the item is checked:

```
if (array_key_exists(strtolower($itemResourceId), $resources)) {
    if ($item->isAllowed()) {
        $resources[$itemResourceId]['checked'] = true;
        array_push($selrids, $itemResourceId);
    }
}
```

I don't know why this is, especially since it seems to work otherwise, but if you change the keys in `adminhtml.xml` from `MyModule`  to `mymodule`  it should work.